# ASP.NET 6 MVC DisplayNameFor() Not Accepting Equivalent Expression?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, crud

I'm working on an ASP.NET 6 MVC project and found something I don't understand in the auto-generated CRUD views.

For context I have a domain model named "Application".  I scaffolded out code to allow me to view a list of applications in an Index page and then pages for create, details, edit, delete applications.  By default, the generated code chose an IEnumerable of my domain class as the view model.

And for some reason this works:

```
@model IEnumerable<launchpad.Models.Application>

<table>
...
    <th>
       @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AppName)
    </th>
...
</table>
```

But if I create a ViewModel that contains an IEnumerable named Applications, this doesn't work and I get error CS1061 "IEnumerable does not contain a definition for AppName...".

```
@model launchpad.ViewModels.ApplicationViewModels.ApplicationsViewModel

<table>
...
    <th>
       @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Applications.AppName)
    </th>
...
</table>
```

I understand why, in principle, the 2nd example doesn't work.  It's more that I don't understand why the first example does.  Aren't these equivalent expressions?

As a more general question, how *should* I handle this?  What's a best practice for accessing the display name for a domain model property across a ViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

You could put your mouse on `model` and check the type of model,and select the method then press F12 to check how the method defined:

For your first view:

[image]

[image]

[image]

For your second view:

[image]

[image]

Acturally the two methods are not same,the fist method is the extension method work for pagemodel type of  `IEnumerable<T>`